# Reading file char by char leads to last line truncation

Tags: c, arrays

I'm creating a simple program for practice purposes and i want to read a text file char by char and save each char read from the file in a 2D char array. So for example if a text file contains the following:

```
******
******
******
******
******
******
```

i need to create a 6x6 `char` array to save the contents of the file. This is my code to read the file and save to the array:

```
// malloc the 2d array here
    i=0;
    j=0;
    clearMap(map,x,y); // set all elements of the array to 0
    while ((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF ) // start reading file here
    {
        if (j == y) // end of line
        {
            j=0;
            i++;
        }
        if (i == x) // end of map
        {
            break;
        }
        map[i][j]=ch; // assign to array
        j++;
    }
    printMap(map,x,y);
```

When i print the array the last line is partially truncated and i get this output on console:

```
******
******
******
******
******
*
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Beware that a new-line counts as `char` (which needs to be and will be read) as well, at least if reading a text file character wise as the code you show does.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Supported by the last line being short by 5 characters (the number of previous lines).Aside, the code is incomplete but you should have defined `ch` as `int` type.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the hint about the number of lines and the number of '\n'. I found out that my array does indeed store the newline as data, thus im 5 chars short. EDIT: Using a check for newline fixed my problem. Thanks alk and Weather Vane.

Comment: Thanks to @alk who drew your attention to the problem.

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, such as this question is doing. post a [mcve]   As it is, we can only guess.  Too much key information is missing from the posted code.